# google chrome extension does not work

Tags: google-chrome-extension, xmlhttprequest

It is a simple extension that invokes Xmlhttprequest to send POST data to a form. I have also added simple message boxes at beginning/end of the js code... The code is being invoked from a background page and correct permissions have been granted in manifest.json.
However when I click on the button for this extension, nothing is happening.

Given below is the js code for the extension-

```
alert("Beginning of code block");
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.open("POST","http://taurusarticlesubmitter.appspot.com/sampleform",true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.send("name=Arvind&description=Test description&email=arvind@taurusseo.com");
alert("End of code block");
```

Also, I added the following code to background.html--

```
<script>
  // Called when the user clicks on the browser action.
  chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(
        null, {file: "cdr.js"});
  });

  chrome.browserAction.setBadgeBackgroundColor({color:[0, 200, 0, 100]});


 </script>
```

Finally, given below is my manifest.json--

```
{
  "name": "My Second Extension",
  "version": "1.0",
  "background_page": "background.html",
  "description": "The second extension that I made.",
   "browser_action": {
        "name": "Data in iframe",
       "default_icon": "icon.png"
},  
"permissions": [ "tabs",
       "bookmarks",
           "http://*/*",
           "https://*/*",
            "unlimitedStorage"
     ]
 }
```

Comment: Why do you have ie6 and ie5 fallback code if this is supposed to be a chrome extension?

Comment: you are right, i removed the ie6/ie5 portion from code...Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that your first code block is `cdr.js`? Then you are **not** running it from the background page. Instead your background page loads a **content script** that tries to send a request. Content scripts run with the privileges of the page that they have been injected into. So if that page doesn't have privileges to send a request to taurusarticlesubmitter.appspot.com then the content script won't have the necessary privileges either.

If your content script needs to perform a privileged action (like sending a request to a third-party page) it should [send a message to the background page](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/messaging.html) and the background page will have to do it.

Comment: Hello, ok what I understood is that in content script I can have something like this-- chrome.extension.sendRequest({greeting: "hello"}, function(response) {
  console.log(response.farewell);
}); And in bg page, listener is like this-- chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    console.log(sender.tab ?
                "from a content script:" + sender.tab.url :
                "from the extension");
    if (request.greeting == "hello")
      sendResponse({farewell: "goodbye"});
    else
      sendResponse({}); // snub them.
  });
Am I correct?Thanks

Comment: Yes, that's how exchanging messages between the content script and the background page works.

Comment: Hello again, I have one more query for you- I want that the content script sends its message to background page only after user clicks on button for the extension- is this possible? how do i do this? Thanks, Arvind.

Comment: @user893664: You better create a new question, comments are not the right place for follow-up questions.